# Start process with admin rights and redirect its output

Tags: vb.net, process, console-application, uac

I'd like to start a process, which is a console application requesting admin rights (`level="requireAdministrator"`). Actually, I've to set the `UseShellExecute` property to `True` to show the UAC request but I'd like also to redirect its output. The problem is that, to redirect a process output, we have to set the `UseShellExecute` property to `False`...

Here's my current code :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim admin As Boolean

    Using p As New Process With {
        .StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo With {
            .FileName = "D:\Drarig29\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AdminRightsConsole\Console\bin\Release\Console.exe",
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True,
            .UseShellExecute = False,
            .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            .CreateNoWindow = True}}
        p.Start()
        Using s As StreamReader = p.StandardOutput
            admin = s.ReadToEnd.Trim()
        End Using
    End Using

    If Button1.Text = "Enable" Then
        If admin Then
            Button1.Text = "Disable"
        End If
    Else
        If admin Then
            Button1.Text = "Enable"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I show the UAC request and redirect the output of the process at the same time ?

Edit : The console application writes a `Boolean` in the `Standard Output`. It returns `True` if it had admin rights and `False` if not.

Comment: I don't want my app to request admin rights...

Comment: if that is all that stdio is used for, you could use the exit code instead

Comment: Good idea Plutonix, but I found another solution!